# how to combine "proxy_pass" and "fastcgi_pass" configure in nginx-php server configure file?

Tags: php, nginx

I want to pass all request start with "/api" to "127.0.0.1:9000" a fastcgi progress.

The php-fpm server is working as 127.0.0.1:9000.

First I use "proxy_pass" like this:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.100/api/;
}
```

I try to pass the request to another server.And then using "fastcgi_pass" to pass it to the php-fpm service progress:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  127.0.0.100;
    root x:xxxxx/;
    location /api/ {
        root   "x:xxxxx";
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        index  index.php;
    }
    location ~ \.php(.*)$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

It's working well now.But does it have some way to config it directly?

---

I need to supplement details with the question.The entry file “index.php” path is "root/api/index.php".